# Recommend OpenSource or Freeware tool to inspect network traffic between two servers

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring, protocols

I am currently in the process of locking down the network communication protocols that are available for use on given Windows application platform.

Can you suggest a freely available tool that will allow me to monitor/identify the commuications protocols that are in use i.e.

- TCP/IP
- http
- https
- FTP
- SFTP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - this should do everything you need.

Comment: Yeah. +1 for wireshark. Great tool.

Comment: Thanks Cybergibbins. Looks to be exactly what I am after.

Comment: Hi John, please mark Cyber's reply as the answer if it fits your need please.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Wireshark already mentioned by Cybergibbons, you could use [TCPDUMP](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

Although Wireshark is way better for what you need.